# how to configure WebLogic server for ArcGIS Server 10.1

Tags: arcgis-server

I wish to deploy arcgis services to a greater population via web maps, but before I do this I must install a web server. I am going to use WebLogic Server, it's used listed as a arcgis server compatible web server. After installing and a couple screens into configuration I have to "Generate a domain configured automatically to support the following products:" ArcGIS server is not listed, I have these options(see image), I'm guessing it may be "WebLogic Advanced Web Services" or "Basic WebLog SIP Server Domain". Thanks in advance everyone.

[image: List of options]

Comment: I think you need do this through web adopter .For more details please check http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01540000028p000000